# MVC Sitemap show only parent nodes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider, sitemapprovider

I want show only my parent nodes in my View.
This is my sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0"           enableLocalization="true">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Test" controller="Test" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Teste2" controller="Test" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Teste3" controller="Test" action="Index"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>  
</mvcSiteMap>
```

How can I use the html helper @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu() to show only the parent nodes, and only the child nodes?
Like this:
Parents:

- Home
- Test

Childs

- About
- Contacts
- Teste2
- Teste3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try for top level

> @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(0, true, false, 1)

Second level

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(2, 1, true)
```

This [tutorial](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/) may help

Comment: If I try that, I got this exception: NullPointerException... Object reference not set to an instance of an object.